# Limit of $\log(z^2-4z+3)$ with $\text{arg}\in (0,2\pi]$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, branch-cuts

I wanted to figure out whether the solution to the following exercise is wrong:

> If $f(z)=\log(\eta(z))$ with $\eta(z)=z^2-4z+3$ and $\text{arg }\eta\in (0,2\pi]$, what is
> $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}f(4-i\varepsilon)?$$

Solution says it is $\log 3-i2\pi$; I got $\log 3+i2\pi$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\eta(4-i\varepsilon)&=(4-i\varepsilon)^2-4(4-i\varepsilon)+3\\
&=16-8i\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2-16+4i\varepsilon+3\\
&=3-4i\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2\\
&\overset{\varepsilon\to 0}{\sim}3-4i\varepsilon=\sqrt{3^2+\varepsilon^2}e^{i\arctan\left(-\frac{4\varepsilon}{3}\right)}\sim 3e^{-i\frac{4\varepsilon}{3}}\overset{\small\arg\eta\in(0,2\pi]}{=\mathrel{\mkern-3mu}=}3e^{i2\pi}
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus,
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\log(\eta(4-i\varepsilon))=\log(3e^{i2\pi})=\log3+i2\pi$$

Comment: Your chain of equalities doesn't make sense at many points. Where is the $\varepsilon^2$ term? The exponentials introduced also seem completely random and unrelated to your expression.

Comment: In the end your answer does seem more reasonable than the solution's but I am very confused as to how you arrived at it.

Comment: Let me rewrite my solution step by step.

Comment: @NinadMunshi  Now each step is more clear.